# Firing the check change event of parent node in ExtJs 4.1 Checkbox TreePanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a simple ExtJS 4.1 checkbox TreePanel. The tree is build on simple logic.

1. If you select all child node of any node, deselect all the child nodes and select the parent node.
2. If you select a parent node, deselect all the child nodes.

Please use following fiddle which mocks the above requirement. 
[Example via fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYqRN/20/)

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    store: {
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                checked: false,
                text: "1 detention",
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    checked: false,
                    text: '1.1 foo',
                    leaf: false,
                    children: [{
                        checked: false,
                        text: "1.1.1 India",
                        expanded: true
                    }, {
                        checked: false,
                        text: "1.1.2 Singapore",
                        expanded: true
                    }, {
                        checked: false,
                        text: "1.1.3 USA",
                        expanded: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    checked: false,
                    text: '1.2 bar',
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                checked: false,
                text: "2 homework",
                expanded: true,
                children: [{
                    checked: false,
                    text: "2.1 book report",
                    leaf: true
                }, {
                    checked: false,
                    text: "2.2 algebra",
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [{
                        checked: false,
                        text: "2.2.1 buy lottery tickets",
                        leaf: true
                    }, {
                        checked: false,
                        text: "2.2.2 buy lottery tickets 2",
                        leaf: true
                    }]
                }, {
                    checked: false,
                    text: "2.3 English report",
                    leaf: true
                }]
            }, {
                checked: false,
                text: "3 buy lottery tickets",
                leaf: true
            }]
        }
    },
    rootVisible: false,
    disableSelection: true,
    //selModel: {mode: 'SIMPLE'},
    listeners: {
        checkchange: function (record, checked, opts) {
            if (!checked) return;
            var parentNode = record.parentNode;

            // Deselect children
            function deselectChildren(record) {
                record.eachChild(function (record) {
                    record.set('checked', false);
                    deselectChildren(record);
                });
            }
            deselectChildren(record);

            // See if all siblings are selected now
            var allSiblingSelected = false;
            if (parentNode) {
                allSiblingSelected = parentNode.childNodes.reduce(function (previous, node) {
                    return previous && node.get('checked');
                }, true);
            }

            if (allSiblingSelected) {
                parentNode.set('checked', true);
                // Apparently won't fire on its own. Below line creates problem
                this.fireEvent('checkchange', parentNode, true, opts);
            }

            // Deselect ancestors
            else {
                while (parentNode) {
                    parentNode.set('checked', false);
                    parentNode = parentNode.parentNode;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When you see the code, you will see that when all the siblings of a node is selected, I manually set the 'checked' config for the parent node as true and then  on line number 96 manually fire the checkchange event of the parent node which will deselect all the child nodes.

**problem**: Some times, this event is not getting fired and inconsistent result is produced by the tree. If I put debug point or use console.log, system fires this event every time.

Interesting thing which I observed is, when you debug the code or use console.log to write some debug info, system will work fine. I assume somehow `checkchange` event is not getting fired at times which I am manually triggering using `fireEvent`.

What options I have to automatically fire checkchange event when I set the 'checked' config for parent node or if I can use any other approach.

Please help

Thank you

Comment: In your actual code (not the fiddle) are you creating the id and parentId fields? Duplicate ids can cause all sorts of craziness in a tree. Just a thought as I cannot re-produce the issue from the fiddle...it works every time.

Comment: Thank you the reply but I am sure the ID's are unique. As far as producing the issue with fiddle is concern, it takes a while to reproduce it. But once you are able to reproduce it, you will see this behavior all the time.