# How to programmatically fire the check change event of a ExtJS 4.1 checkbox tree panel

Tags: extjs, event-handling, extjs4.1

I have a ExtJs 4.1 check box tree panel. When I check or uncheck any node, check change event for the tree is fired. How can I programmatically fire this event.

One way I can think of is to use following code. But this code is not firing every time :-(

```
this.fireEvent('checkchange', node, true, opts);
```

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firing the check change event of parent node in ExtJs 4.1 Checkbox TreePanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060875/firing-the-check-change-event-of-parent-node-in-extjs-4-1-checkbox-treepanel)

Answer (score 0):

try with this event

```
checkchange(node, checked, eOpts)
```